# Requisição ajax reexecuta chamada para controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, .net

Fala ai pessoal.
Estou com um problema em cadastro de itens, quando lista uma série de itens e eu clico em adicionar abre uma nova modal com as caracteristicas do item que será adicionado. Entretanto quando clico em não e retorno para listagem de itens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faço isso 3 vezes por exemplo, na última quando finalmente clico em Sim para adicionar, ele chama minha função GravarItem().

```
$('#tbl-item-cadastrado tbody').on('click', 'input[type=button]', function () {
var table = $('#tbl-item-cadastrado').DataTable();
var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado').modal('show');

//Preencher modal com informações do item
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-quantidade').val('');
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricao').val('');

$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-desconto').val(data.PercDescPadrao);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-name').text(data.CodigoItem);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricao').val(data.DescricaoCurta);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricaoLonga').val(data.DescricaoLonga);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-modelo').val(data.Modelo);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #lote-minimo').val(data.LotMinimo);

$("#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #btn-add-item-cadastrado").bind("click", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    openLoader();

    setTimeout(function () { GravarItem(); }, 3000);
});


function GravarItem() {

    var codigoItem = '';
    var quantidade = 1;
    var descricao = '';
    var desconto = 0;
    var descontoView = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-desconto').val();

    if (descontoView.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        descontoView = descontoView.replace('.', '');
    }

    if (descontoView.indexOf(',') != -1) {
        descontoView = descontoView.replace(',', '.');
    }

    codigoItem = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-name').text();
    quantidade = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-quantidade').val() > 0 ? $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-quantidade').val() : 1;
    descricao = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricao').val();
    desconto = parseFloat(descontoView) > 0 ? parseFloat(descontoView) : 0;
    //alert(desconto);
    descricaoLonga = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricaoLonga').val();
    modelo = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-modelo').val();
    LotMinimo = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #lote-minimo').val();

    var item = new ItemCotacaoCadastrado(codigoItem, quantidade, desconto, descricao, descricaoLonga, modelo, 0, LotMinimo, false);
    item.PercDescFinal = adicionaFuncionalidadeDescontoNegativoPeloInputRadioSelecionado(item);
    //Carlos Pamplona 29/01/2019- Inclui o item no itemCotacao
    //alert(item.PercDescFinal);

    itemCotacao.push(item);

    var clientModel = new CriarViewModel();
    if (clientModel.Cotacao.CodigoVendedorExternoCotacao == "Indisponível" || clientModel.Cotacao.CodigoVendedorExternoCriacao == "Indisponível") {
        ExibirAlerta("Atenção!", "Precisa selecionar um vendedor externo para continuar.");
        closeLoader();
        return;
    }
    var obj = { cliente: clientModel.Cliente, cotacao: clientModel.Cotacao, itemCotacao: clientModel.ItemCotacao };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../Cotacao/Criar',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success: function (response) {

            var obj = JSON.parse(response);

            if (obj.HttpStatusCode == "200") {

                RedirectTelaEditar(obj.ObjResponse);
            }
            else {

                closeLoader();
                ExibirAlerta('Atenção', 'Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar a cotação - Error Codigo: 01.');
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {

            closeLoader();
            ExibirAlerta('Atenção', responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

});

Eu até coloquei um debugger no inicio da função do ajax, um no retorno do ajax, e um no meu método da controller, mas o problema é que ele entra na função JS 1 vez, executa meu método na controller 3 vezes (a mesma quantidade de vezes que visualizei os itens na listagem), depois que finaliza que cai no callback do ajax com sucesso, nisso ele adicionar 3 vezes o mesmo item.

Comment: Não use `async: false,` no AJAX. O AJAX deve ser assíncrono.

Comment: Tem que ver também como vc está abrindo a modal.

Comment: Atualizado a pergunta com o trecho que abre a modal.

Comment: como vc ta passando um objeto ele deve ta armazenando em memoria, experimente zerar tudo ao fechar o  botão que vc abre o modal - > 'eu clico em adicionar abre uma nova modal '.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução.
No evento click do button da minha tbody estava criando eventos de click para o botao de add item, portanto sempre que eu add um item a abria a modal, era adicionado mais um evento click ao botão, assim quando adicionei pela terceira vez (por exemplo) ele executou a minha função GravarItem() 3 vezes.
Os ajustes que fizeram funcionar ficou assim:

```
$('#tbl-item-cadastrado tbody').on('click', 'input[type=button]', function () {
var table = $('#tbl-item-cadastrado').DataTable();
var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado').modal('show');

//Preencher modal com informações do item
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-quantidade').val('');
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricao').val('');

$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-desconto').val(data.PercDescPadrao);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-name').text(data.CodigoItem);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricao').val(data.DescricaoCurta);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricaoLonga').val(data.DescricaoLonga);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-modelo').val(data.Modelo);
$('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #lote-minimo').val(data.LotMinimo);
```

});

```
$("#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #btn-add-item-cadastrado").bind("click", function (event) {

event.preventDefault();

openLoader();

setTimeout(function () { GravarItem(); }, 3000);
```

});

```
function GravarItem() {

var codigoItem = '';
var quantidade = 1;
var descricao = '';
var desconto = 0;
var descontoView = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-desconto').val();

if (descontoView.indexOf('.') != -1) {
    descontoView = descontoView.replace('.', '');
}

if (descontoView.indexOf(',') != -1) {
    descontoView = descontoView.replace(',', '.');
}

codigoItem = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-name').text();
quantidade = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-quantidade').val() > 0 ? $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-quantidade').val() : 1;
descricao = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricao').val();
desconto = parseFloat(descontoView) > 0 ? parseFloat(descontoView) : 0;
//alert(desconto);
descricaoLonga = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-descricaoLonga').val();
modelo = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #recipient-modelo').val();
LotMinimo = $('#modal-container-complemento-item-cadastrado #lote-minimo').val();

var item = new ItemCotacaoCadastrado(codigoItem, quantidade, desconto, descricao, descricaoLonga, modelo, 0, LotMinimo, false);
item.PercDescFinal = adicionaFuncionalidadeDescontoNegativoPeloInputRadioSelecionado(item);
//Carlos Pamplona 29/01/2019- Inclui o item no itemCotacao
//alert(item.PercDescFinal);

itemCotacao.push(item);

var clientModel = new CriarViewModel();
if (clientModel.Cotacao.CodigoVendedorExternoCotacao == "Indisponível" || clientModel.Cotacao.CodigoVendedorExternoCriacao == "Indisponível") {
    ExibirAlerta("Atenção!", "Precisa selecionar um vendedor externo para continuar.");
    closeLoader();
    return;
}
var obj = { cliente: clientModel.Cliente, cotacao: clientModel.Cotacao, itemCotacao: clientModel.ItemCotacao };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../Cotacao/Criar',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    success: function (response) {

        var obj = JSON.parse(response);

        if (obj.HttpStatusCode == "200") {

            RedirectTelaEditar(obj.ObjResponse);
        }
        else {

            closeLoader();
            ExibirAlerta('Atenção', 'Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar a cotação - Error Codigo: 01.');
        }
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {

        closeLoader();
        ExibirAlerta('Atenção', responseText);
    }
});
```

}